# How to create a new column in Python Dataframe by referencing two other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b'], 'Year':[1999,1999,1999,2000,1999,2000,2000], 'Name_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2]})

  Name  Name_id  Year
0    a        1  1999
1    a        1  1999
2    a        1  1999
3    a        1  2000
4    b        2  1999
5    b        2  2000
6    b        2  2000
```

What I'd like to have is a new column 'yr_name_id' that increases for each unique Name_id-Year combination and then begins anew with each new Name_id.

```
  Name  Name_id  Year  yr_name_id
0    a        1  1999           1
1    a        1  1999           1
2    a        1  1999           1
3    a        1  2000           2
4    b        2  1999           1
5    b        2  2000           2
6    b        2  2000           2
```

I've tried a variety of things and looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420187/getting-previous-row-values-from-within-pandas-apply-function), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698415/reference-previous-row-when-iterating-through-dataframe) and at a few posts on groupby and enumerate.

At first I tried creating a unique dictionary after combining Name_id and Year and then using map to assign values, but when I try to combine Name_id and Year as strings via:

```
df['yr_name_id'] = str(df['Name_id']) + str(df['Year'])
```

The new column has a non-unique syntax of `0  0    1\n1    1\n2    1\n3    1\n4    2\n5    2...` which I don't really understand.

A more promising approach that I think I just need help with the lambda is by using groupby

```
df['yr_name_id'] =  df.groupby(['Name_id', 'Year'])['Name_id'].transform(lambda x: )#unsure from this point
```

I am very unfamiliar with lambda's so any guidance on how I might do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [99]: df['yr_name_id'] = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(df['Name_id'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Year'].astype(str))[0] + 1)

In [100]: df
Out[100]:
  Name  Name_id  Year yr_name_id
0    a        1  1999          1
1    a        1  1999          1
2    a        1  1999          1
3    a        1  2000          2
4    b        2  1999          3
5    b        2  2000          4
6    b        2  2000          4

In [101]: df.dtypes
Out[101]:
Name            object
Name_id          int64
Year             int64
yr_name_id    category
dtype: object
```

But looking at your desired DF, it looks like you want to categorize just a `Year` column, **not** a combination of `Name_id` + `Year`

```
In [102]: df['yr_name_id'] = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(df.Year)[0] + 1)

In [103]: df
Out[103]:
  Name  Name_id  Year yr_name_id
0    a        1  1999          1
1    a        1  1999          1
2    a        1  1999          1
3    a        1  2000          2
4    b        2  1999          1
5    b        2  2000          2
6    b        2  2000          2

In [104]: df.dtypes
Out[104]:
Name            object
Name_id          int64
Year             int64
yr_name_id    category
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.count`:

```
from itertools import count

counter = count(1)
df['yr_name_id'] = (df.groupby(['Name_id', 'Year'])['Name_id']
                      .transform(lambda x: next(counter)))
```

Output:

```
  Name  Name_id  Year  yr_name_id
0    a        1  1999           1
1    a        1  1999           1
2    a        1  1999           1
3    a        1  2000           2
4    b        2  1999           3
5    b        2  2000           4
6    b        2  2000           4
```